# ¿Como puedo redireccionar un código embebido/incrustado en Wordpress?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Tengo una aplicación web en Wordpress y le embebi/incruste un formulario que tengo en un **subdominio** y quiero que al terminar **refresque o redireccione** a otra pagina que esta dentro del Wordpress.

Ustedes han hecho algo así, podrían colaborar con ello?

Yo intente lo tradicional y no funciona:

```
<script> window.location = 'https://minegocio.com/thankpage'; </script>
```

Para ser mas explicito agregare el código embebido que tengo en Wordpress:

```
<iframe src="http://forms.midominio.com/cotizador/" style="width:100%; height:1050px;"></iframe>
```

Y el código que tengo en **http://forms.minegocio.com/cotizador/** es el siguiente:

```
<form name="frmContacto" method="post" action="sendbymail.php">
    <div class="row" style="text-align:center;">
        <label> Todos los elementos con * son obligatorios. </label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
            <label for="first_name">Nombre Completo * </label><br>      
        </div>
        <div class="col-75">
            <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="25" placeholder="Ej: Pedro Rodriguez Alcantara" required><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
            <label for="email">Correo * </label><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-75">
            <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="35" placeholder="Ej: juanrodriguez892@gmail.com" required><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
            <label for="telephone">Teléfono * </label><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-75">
            <input type="tel" name="telephone" pattern="[0-9]{10}" required placeholder="Ej: 5567736255"><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-25">
            <label for="comments">Mensaje * </label><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-75">
            <textarea name="comments" maxlength="500" cols="30" rows="5" required></textarea><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </div>

</form>
```

**sendbyemail.php** tiene el siguiente código despues de recibir la info y validar:

```
echo "<script> window.location = 'https://minegocio.com/thankpage'; </script>";
```

Comment: Si el usuario tiene que interactuar con tu formulario por medio de un boton puedes agregar el link en este con wordpress

Comment: No te entiendo amigo, ya agregue código para explicar la situación.